# High CPU usage when using numpy and connectionreseterror

Tags: python, numpy, celery

We are using prophet library as microservice for some forecasting work and we use kombu library for consuming RabbitMQ messages. Initially, we encountered high CPU usage issue in the microservice applications. I followed instructions provided https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1109 and set env variables as below.

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

This resolved the high CPU usage, but we started encountering below error when application is run as a microservice

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I'm not sure which of these environment variables are linked to kombu internal libraries. I'm wondering if there is a way to fix the high CPU usage without encountering connection reset error.

Minimum reproducible example for high CPU usage from https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1109

```
import numpy as np

for _ in range(10000):
    z = np.zeros((674,14))
    z2 = np.zeros((1,14))
    np.matmul(z, z2.transpose())
```

Tried to reproduce the error and fix it, but didn't work and encountered another error.

Comment: Are you sure that restricting the number of threads is causing the ConnectionResetErrors? That seems really strange, and I can't think of a reason which would cause that.

Comment: Numpy using multiple threads for computation is an intended behavior. If you're looking for a more targeted fix than those environment variables, you can use the [threadpoolctl](https://pypi.org/project/threadpoolctl/) package. This package is capable of changing the parallelism level for OMP and BLAS. I've used it before to keep numpy from using parallelism when it was not wanted.

Comment: @NickODell, Once we reverted back the changes, we didn't encounter the connection reset error anymore. We encountered them but only 1% of what we encountered before making those changes. Your second comment is what I'm interested in. Can you share any such example if there is one.

Comment: I have an example of how to use threadpoolctl on [my blog](https://njodell.com/?p=74), including a jupyter notebook. In my case, I already had one model being fit on each core, so numpy also being parallelized was counterproductive.